# How to transform array into string?

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3

I'm doing this project that I need to save a full character array into a string. I want to have the `[]` characters in the string.

```
Example:
aArray = [
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0]
];

myString = aArray.toString();
trace(myString);
```

In my output I get:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
```

I want the `[]` brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aArray:Array = [
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0]
];

var string:String =  JSON.encode(aArray);

trace(string);
```

output :

```
"[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]"
```

Comment: What i have to import to use that?

Comment: If you are going to use JSON.encode you need https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib. If you target flash player 11 and up you can use the native JSON class and JSON.stringify method.